# SAP HANA Audit logs Users

Tags: sql, hana, audit

We've some HANA audit policies already defined in the systems. There are 2 audit policies that have some users in the exclusion list. The number of users seems quite long, so need some help if there is SQL query to perform the task?

Thank you.

- Jack

SQL query to list those users in the exclusion list in HANA audit policies